# Generate a PDF file from HTML using Parse.com cloud code

Tags: pdf, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is it possible to generate a PDF file from HTML using Parse.com cloud code?

I haven't found anything useful in this regard, just a bunch of archived questions from the Parse.com questions website that were never answered.

The nature of the project and environment forbids us from using 3rd party servers or SAAS for generating PDF's, and Parse.com is one of the few companies we have used that we're allow to share our data with.

The data for the PDF will be generated on the user's mobile device so we can't do anything that requires a local device installation.

Thanks

Comment: hi Greg, did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: Nope, had to go with a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out wkhtmltopdf http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

You can install it locally.

Comment: The data for the PDF will be generated on the user's mobile device so we can't do anything that requires a local device installation.

Comment: Dear Greg; You may want to check the Jasper Report where the mobile edition exists in the following link; http://community.jaspersoft.com/mobile